# jQuery read attribute value with spaces

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following html:

```
<div type="Text with spaces" eventid="57" class="movie">...</div>
```

How can I read the `type` attribute with jQuery?

I tried this:

```
var type = $(".movie").attr("type");
```

but `type` contains only `Text`.

**UPDATE:**
This is how I was using this variable:

```
 $("#publicationBlock").load("/Publication/EventSchedule?eventId=" + eventId + "&type=" + type
```

In the action, I get only `Text`.

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using? The above code works fine for me with jq 1.7.2 and 1.8.3 and even 1.6.4

Comment: Can you check your source html to make sure that the double quotes are present around the value

Comment: I just had this problem. It is caused by not using quotes around value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should work.

```
var type=$(".movie").attr("type");
alert(type);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W34Ma/) here..

see if u missing this.
1)  make sure your code is inside ready function `$(function(){`..
2) check the jquery version.. latest is better

**updated**

```
<div type="Text_with_spaces" eventid="57" class="movie">...</div>
```

and explode with '_' in your `EventSchedule` function

Comment: Hmm. It seems the problem in other side. Check update in question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem here?

This example is exactly the same as your code, but it was able to display the entire attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/rFYpE/

```
var type = $(".movie").attr("type");
alert(type);
```

How are you using the variable type?