# How do I retrieve textblock value with onclick handler and show it using alert function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

code:

```
<a class='link' href='javascript:void(0)' id='".str_replace(" ",'-',$sub_head)."'>
    <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>&nbsp;".$sub_head."
</a>
<input type='text' name='tag' class='tag' value='' />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".link").bind("click", function() { 
            link = $(this).attr( 'id' );
            tag = $(".tag").val(link);
            alert(tag);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this code I have create a link where class has to be define as link and inside id having dynamic value. Now what I want when I click on link then id of  tag go to input field i.e tag. Now what happen When I click on link it show me [object Object] in alert box but I want value. So, How can I do this?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Stop using alert, use `console.log()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery read attribute value with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453307/jquery-read-attribute-value-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$(".tag").val(link)` set value for `$(".tag")` and it return `object` you should use `.val()` to get value of `$(".tag")` or you can alert value directly with `alert(link);` it return same value as `$(".tag").val()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".link").bind("click", function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".tag").val(link);
    val = $(".tag").val();
    alert(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='link' href='javascript:void(0)' id='5678'>
  <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i> Click
</a>
<input type='text' name='tag' class='tag' value='' />
```

Answer (score 1):

This line makes the input tag get a new value, but also returns just the input element:

```
tag = $(".tag").val(link);
```

Then the next line is actually alerting the entire input element object:

```
alert(tag);
```

To only alert the value of the input element, write:

```
tag = $(".tag")
tag.val(link); 
alert(tag.val());
```

You can see the difference between val(arg) and val() in jquery's documentation at http://api.jquery.com/val/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, it's working fine for your requirements.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        $(".link").on("click", function() { 
           var link = $(this).attr( 'id' );
            var tag = $(".tag").val(link);
            alert($(".tag").val());
        });
    });
```

```html
   
  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='link' href='javascript:void(0)' id='id_1'>
    <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i>&nbsp;Sub Heading
</a>
<input type='text' name='tag' class='tag' value='' />
```